# Passing derived type into out parameter

Tags: c#, ienumerable, out

I have a function with the following signature:

```
IEnumerable<TypeA> GetItems(string s, out IEnumerable<TypeB> otherItems)
```

(For the record, `TypeA` and `TypeB` are unrelated types, my question doesn't involve them other than as placeholders).

In the code where I call this function, I would like to place the return value and the `out` parameter value into `List` fields of my class, as I want to be sure they are enumerated and I perform List-specific operations shortly after.

Consider:

```
private List<TypeA> _fieldA;
private List<TypeB> _fieldB;

// ... other code

// conversion errors for _fieldA and _fieldB:
_fieldA = Fns.GetItems(str, out _fieldB);

// _fieldA is now ok, but not _fieldB:
_fieldA = Fns.GetItems(str, out _fieldB).ToList();

// Same result as previous, out param must be a variable.
_fieldA = Fns.GetItems(str, out _fieldB.AsEnumerable()).ToList();

// This works but makes me sad:
IEnumerable<TypeB> tempEnumerable;
_fieldA = Fns.GetItems(str, out tempEnumerable).ToList();
_fieldB = tempEnumerable.ToList();
```

Basically, is that fourth attempt the best way of getting what I need, or is there a "better" way to get Lists out of that function (short of modifying the function, which is not possible)?

Comment: Do you mean the 4th attempt? If so, yes, that's all there is. You can't pass the field directly into the method, as it's the wrong type. `out` and `ref` parameter arguments have to be exactly the same type as the parameter.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot define `_fieldA` and `_fieldB` as `IEnumerable<>` instead of `List<>`?

Comment: Er, fourth yes. I'm pretty good at counting to two, still working on the rest.

Comment: @juharr No reason I _can't_ but I would end up `ToList()`ing them multiple times throughout the rest of the class in order to add and remove items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot modify the function's signature, create a wrapper function for it: (Whether it be another overload of that method, or a method in another class if need be.)

```
//TODO come up with a better name
List<TypeA> GetItemsAsLists(string s, out List<TypeB> otherItems)
{
    IEnumerable<TypeB> tempEnumerable;
    var output = Fns.GetItems(s, out tempEnumerable).ToList();
    otherItems = tempEnumerable.ToList();
    return output.ToList();
}
```

At some point, somewhere, you're going to have to have a variable of type `IEnumerable<TypeB>` to call that method.  You can hide it (like in the above case) but it'll have to exist at some point, somewhere.

Comment: Alright, I had a suspicion that would be the case, but wasn't sure if there was some niche extension method or other way out there that would tidy that up a bit.

Comment: @helrich It's situations like this why the use of `out`/`ref` should generally be avoided.  You'll find that good APIs won't use it at all.

Comment: I can see where they were coming from with that decision, both sequences depend on each other and are calculated from each other, so why not return them both in the same call? I would have preferred a `Tuple` over this though!

Comment: @helrich That's just it; they should have returned a method that composed both sequences.  (Probably a new named type, rather than `Tuple`.)